# SSRS External Image not consistently shown

Tags: reporting-services

I'm running into a problem recently with a report that uses an external image. The image will be displayed fine, but after an unknown period of time the image will no longer be displayed even though the rest of the report runs fine. I am able to navigate out to the network path and see the image manually and as the report can view the image previously the account has permissions to the network drive. 
As a temporary fix we can restart the service and the image is back to being displayed. Is there a root cause or permanent fix for this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't download the image and embed it into the report?

Comment: Embed to get around it sounds like the best bet. Sometimes it sounds like the service is not successfully reaching the image on the network (could be many causes of that, though)

Comment: The image paths are based on user selection so I can't embed them as I don't know the path until run-time.